# Does the miner machine get any other type of reward except confirmation of transaction in bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, mining-reward

Does the miner machine get any other type of reward except confirmation of transaction in bitcoin?(The answer precedes ​another question)

Answer (score 1):

As a result of mining, miners receive income from two sources

- The mining reward per block, which halves approximately every 4 years.
- The transaction fees for the transactions the miner includes in the block.

Nothing else.

The miner includes as the first transaction in the block (the "coinbase" transaction) a transaction with no inputs and with outputs to one or more addresses of their choice with a total amount which is less than or equal to the sum of other included transactions fees and the current mining reward .

Comment: this is acceptable miners get a reward for proof of work(confirmation transactions the second reward you were mention) but what exactly do miners when say they have a process for creating a block(and get a reward for them)? (In other words what exactly this process? Is it possible to remove it?)